# mentioning column names dynamically in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to select certain columns of my table. However, instead of writing them as part of my select statement, I would like to populate it dynamically.

Say, I would like to select all columns starting with the word 'Subsequent' of the table Mytable. I am able to select columns as follows

```
select name from sys.columns where object_id=OBJECT_ID('Mytable') and name like 'Subsequent%'
```

I was thinking that mentioning it as a subquery as follows would work, but I wasn't able to get it to work.

```
select top 100 (select name from sys.columns where object_id=OBJECT_ID('Mytable') and name like 'Subsequent%') from Mytable
```

Comment: Use built in SP sp_executesql.

Comment: You have to use dynamic sql for this.

Comment: Agreed. Can't do it. Use dynamic SQL with sp_executesql if you absolutely have to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use dynamic sql to inject the columns into the select list of the statement. This is one way to do it:

```
declare @Table SYSNAME;
declare @cols nvarchar(max);
declare @sql nvarchar(max); 

 SET @Table = N'TableName';

select @cols = stuff(
    (select ',' + quotename(name)   
     from sys.columns 
     where object_id=object_id(@Table) 
     and name like 'Subsequent%'
     for xml path(''), type)
    .value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'),1,1,'') 

set @sql = N'select ' + @cols + N' from '+ QUOTENAME(@Table)
exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: it seems like I have copy pasted your answer, but trust me I havent :)

Comment: @M.Ali Didn't think so :) You handle the table as a variable which is smarter than my hard coded solution.

Comment: @jpw I'm sorry, I'm new to this. When use the command above, I only get "Commands completed successfully", I don't see any output.

Comment: @IAMTubby It shouldn't matter; I tried with both table and views without any issues.

Comment: @jpw, hmm it does. But instead of 'TableName' from your query above, I put the name of the my table and I get an invalid object name on the name of my table. However, if I just use the command which I mentioned in the original post, it display the names, which means it does exist in my database. Btw, I'm querying a view, not a table. Does that matter?

Comment: @jpw, the table I'm trying to query is of the form, schemaname.tablename. Does that matter? Say, I replace the TableName above with, ,I get Invalid object name 'schemaname.tablename'. But If I do, select name from sys.columns where object_id=OBJECT_ID('schemaname.tablename') and name like 'Subsequent%' , I do get the names of the tables I want to query.

Comment: @IAMTubby Try changing `+ QUOTENAME(@Table)` to just `+ @Table` in the statement at the end and it should work with _schemaname.objectname_